# how to add a run-time parameter to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am having the following logic where am getting the version.txt from a static network location,i want to change the .cmd file to pass it as an argument and make it dynamic,can anyone suggest how to
do it?

```
REM ADDING LOGIC TO GET THE BUILD_VER FROM NETWORK LOCATION
set $NetPath="\\Network\path\version.txt"
set /p version=<\\Network\path\version.txt
set BUILD_VER=%version%
echo %BUILD_VER%
```

Comment: So, do you mean you don't want to use 'version.txt'? You just want to use argument as version value?

Comment: no,argument will be the version.text path

Answer (score 2):

```
REM ADDING LOGIC TO GET THE BUILD_VER FROM NETWORK LOCATION
set $NetPath="%~1"
set /p version=<%$NetPath%
...
```

run as

```
whateveryourbatnameis \\Network\path\version.txt
```

Enclose the argument in "quotes" if it contains spaces.